# Pagination with dynamic records

Tags: sorting, pagination

Imagine a site with 1,000 pages, with 20 pics on each page. Sorting is done by rating, and since site is very popular, ratings for pics are changed very frequently (rating is based on number of votes). One pic might have rating 5.6, and 5 mins later 5.9 and so on.

There is a problem when visitor is browsing site - on some pages he'll see pics he alredy saw on one of previous pages (because in meantine rating is changed for some pics).
I don't know what is the proper solution for this. Do I need to make changes in script so site will remember order of ALL pics when user start browsing? Also, new pics are added every minute or two, so they needs to be visible too.

What is the best approach for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Think about how the ratings will change.. if it really is so popular then the ratings will not change so much unless the image is new. For new images a rating could change considerably but the divergence will decrease upon each rating. You may just want to put something saying the image is 'hot' or 'trending' or something similar.